# Flutter bloc: should every event generate a state?

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

Is it mandatory for every event added to the bloc to generate a state (concerning the principles of the BLoC pattern)?

Example --

```
User clicks on the "Share on Whatsapp" button
We add the event for it 
We do the logic inside the bloc in an if (event is ShareOnWhatsapp) condition
We do not generate a state back cause the UI doesn't need a rebuild
```

Is this okay to do with BLoC?

Would really appreciate references!

Comment: It's alright but you might be using Share plugin inside the bloc. Pedantically, the bloc should not contain anything flutter related. So you should emit a state which tells the UI to Share the content to Whatsapp which you can handle on Flutter side (widgets) by using BlocListener. Immediately after the handling, you can add another event to tell bloc that sharedToWhatsapp has done.

Comment: Got it! Can you share why it's not a good practice to have flutter related anything inside the bloc ? Thanks!!

Comment: there are two libraries. bloc and flutter_bloc. The bloc class you extends from is actually from the bloc library. flutter_bloc only contains widgets which you use on the UI side. Also, if you have framework independent bloc, you can use it with other frameworks as well. It's easier to translate the logic into other languages as well because of no framework dependency.